# setState counter showing up as NaN

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, setstate

my code:

```
import React from "react"

export default class MenuItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { value: this.props.value }
    }
    updateValue(newValue) {
        let propertyName =
            this.state.selectedItem.objType === "number" ? "value" : "strValue"
        console.log(propertyName)
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            let objectToUpdate = prevState.currentObjects.find(

        )
        objectToUpdate[propertyName] = newValue
        return { currentObjects: this.state.currentObjects }
    })
}
data = [
    { itemId: 1 },
]

addTen() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        let newValue = prevState.value + 1
        return {
            value: newValue,
        }
    })
}

subTen() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        let newValue = prevState.value - 1
        this.setState({ newValue })
        return {
            value: newValue,
        }
    })
}

render() {
    let array = this.data.map((itemPrice, itemName) => {
        return (<div>
            <p>${this.props.itemPrice}</p>
            <h2>{this.props.itemName}</h2>
            <p>{this.props.itemDescription}</p>
            <button onClick={() => this.addTen()}>Add to Cart</button>
            <p> Item Count: {this.state.value}</p>

            <button onClick={() => this.addTen()}>Add One</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.subTen()}>Subtract One</button>
        </div>
        )
    })
    return (array)
}
}
```

The problem is that when I go to use the add or subtract button I get this
[picture of item count: NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlyCD.png)

Basically, I am trying to get the button to add or subtract one count when the button is pushed but it is not doing that, instead, it is just showing up as NaN. Also, there is no count of 0 even in the beginning. I have to press the button to make even NaN pop up. I don't know why. any suggestions? I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: is objectToUpdate[propertyName] = newValue this a number? Try casting it to an integer - objectToUpdate[propertyName] = parseInt(newValue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a couple of changes needed to happen here. First off in your constructor you never gave value a default value therefore setState returned NaN when trying to add 1 to an undefined value. Constructor for reference:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 0 };
  }
```

One other change is to your subTen() method. You called this.setState twice inside of hit here is the updated version:

```
  subTen() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let newValue = prevState.value - 1;
      return {
        value: newValue
      };
    });
  }
```